# Dimensions of App Store Connect Screenshots

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, screenshot

I have uploaded screenshots for my app based on what Apple have said in their [screenshot specifications](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/).

I am worried as when I upload them to `App Store Connect`, they shrink and appear blurry, but when I click on them to view them, they are very high resolution.

When putting app icons into `Xcode` a similar thing happens: they look awful, but on the real devices they look great.

Will the screenshots look alright? (The dimensions they provide are still not what they will show as unless the user views them full screen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, the screenshots will look alright. Screenshot sizes are equal to device screen sizes, so even in full screen everything will look good. When I uploaded icons and screenshots to App Store Connect they also were blurred, but on App Store they were alright.